# Can't build IOS app from CLI after react-native upgrade

Tags: ios, react-native

After upgrade from react-native 0.70.6 to 0.73.4 I am able to build successfully in xcode and build for android using react-native run-android. But, react-native run-ios causes this error:

```
error xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:.
Error: xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
    at getInfo (/Users/irosenba/rooms/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/tools/getInfo.js:29:13)
    at getConfiguration (/Users/irosenba/rooms/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/buildIOS/getConfiguration.js:34:37)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/irosenba/rooms/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js:115:52)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/irosenba/rooms/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:118:9)
```

I have tried deleting node_modules and reinstalling, deleting podlock and reinstalling, fully disintegrating pods and reinstalling, clearing npm cache, and clearing pod cache

Comment: This is my workaround, it'd be nice to be able to use react-native run-ios again though.

`cd ios; xcodebuild -workspace rooms.xcworkspace -scheme rooms -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15 Pro Max' -quiet; xcrun simctl boot 'iPhone 15 Pro Max'; xcrun simctl launch booted com.uwmadison.rooms`